# Confirming a contact by setting a column value to 1

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have listed my contact lists on the admin's Activity to confirm them by changing the value of `etat` from 0 to 1 column, but when I do that all my contacts in the list are confirmed

database:

```
public void SETETAT(Contact e) {

      //helper.insertContact(c);
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String query=" update contacts set etat='1' where id="+COLUMN_ID;
    Cursor ce=db.rawQuery(query ,null);
    int count=ce.getCount();
    e.getId();
    e.getEmail();
    e.getName();
    e.getPass();
    e.getPhone();
    e.getRepass();
    values.put(COLUMN_ETAT, e.getEtat());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

the list

```
public class Tab2 extends Activity implements              OnItemClickListener{
    Cursor cursor;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    String info;
    ListView datalist;
    ArrayList<String> databaseList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onglet1);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        datalist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste);
        List<Contact> values = db.getAllContact();

        ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(Tab2.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        datalist.setAdapter(adapter);
        datalist.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, Approuver.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

here's the Button code

```
public void con(View v)  {
    Contact e=new Contact();
    helper.SETETAT(e);
    Toast m = Toast.makeText(Approuver.this, "demande approuvé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    m.show();
}
```

Comment: Why does the button call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`? If you want to load a new layout, use Fragments

Comment: that's not a problem it's  just a test tnk you so much cricket for the observation i will use fragments

Comment: I don't quite understand where the problem is, then... You did make `new Contact()`, then `SETETAT`, with that, but it won't have any value in it as it is a new object. Also, I don't think `UPDATE` sql query is returning anything. You need to `SELECT` the updated value

Comment: i didn't understand what you just said :(

Comment: i'm trying to update  the etat from  to one

Comment: And that is exactly what the code should be doing, no? `update contacts set etat='1' where id="+COLUMN_ID`... ? The only reason you would see all the contacts have the same value is if `COLUMN_ID` is the same on every row of the database

Answer (score 0):

> but when i do that all my contacts in the list are confirmed

Then your query is wrong.

```
String query=" update contacts set etat='1' where id="+COLUMN_ID;
```

You can play around with SQLite outside of Android. That might be a good way to debug the problem.

---

If I understand correctly, though, you are trying to update a contact of a row when it's clicked.

In order to do so, I think you should use that `Contact.getID()` method that is available.

So, move the adapter / list into member variables

```
ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.onglet1);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    datalist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(Tab2.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.getAllContact());
    datalist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then, in the listener, you want to only update the item you clicked. I don't understand all the get methods you called needlessly or the insert query with content values.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final Contact item = adapter.getItem(position);
    SQLiteDatabase database = db.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values  = new ContentValues();
    values.put("etat", 1);
    database.update("contacts", values, "id=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(item.getId()) });
    database.close();
}
```

Comment: i tryed this but the item is not clickable can you tell me how to make it clickabl i'm lost

Comment: and it gives me an error at this line       final Contact item = adapter.getItem(position);
it demnde to cast that to contact type

Comment: another problem that after confirming the first contact it doesn't confir no other one

Comment: I don't know what "confirm" means, but try this code with the edit. You've already got the click listener set to the listview

Comment: i ment i want to set evry contact's etat to 1 by clicking att them

Comment: but it confirms all the contact at the same time ...i wana confirm one by one

Comment: Again "confirm" means what? A dialog box? That isn't possible unless you loop manually and confirm yourself, which is too broad to answer here

Comment: confirm means to give a contact the possibility to do the login and access to the app after doing the sign up it's like facebook when you accept a friend  request